# How put dates on flot

Tags: postgresql, time, axis, flot, curve

I've a little problem, I need to do a curve with on y axis numbers and x axis dates.. but I can't display some dates...
My code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

<?php

echo "   var data = [";
$cpt="0";

include ('../connect.php');
// Requete SQL
$req = 'select "SPP_NB_IND" from "STAT_PERPHY" where "SPP_SAGES" = \''.$sages.'\' AND "SPP_DATE" between \''.$jourtableau.' 00:00:00\' and \''.$jourfinw.' 23:59:59\'';
$res = pg_query($req);

$reqd = 'select "SPP_DATE" from "STAT_PERPHY" where "SPP_SAGES" = \''.$sages.'\' AND "SPP_DATE" between \''.$jourtableau.' 00:00:00\' and \''.$jourfinw.' 23:59:59\' AND "SPP_NB_IND" IS NOT NULL ';
$resd = pg_query($reqd);

// On met les valeurs obtenues dans un tableau
while ( $row = pg_fetch_assoc ($res) )
{
 //echo $row['SPP_NB_IND']."<br>"; 
 $var=$row['SPP_NB_IND'];
        while ( $roww = pg_fetch_assoc ($resd) )
        {
        $abscisse=date('d-m', strtotime($roww['SPP_DATE']));
        }
 echo "[$abscisse, $var],";
 $cpt++;
}
echo "];";
?>
var options = {
                lines: {
                        show: true
                },
                points: { show: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                        mode: "time",
                        timeformat : "%d/%m"
                }
};
<?php
echo "$.plot($(\"#graph1\"), [ data ], options);";

?>
});
</script>
```

[/CODE]

When I put $abscisse, my curve is vertical and if I put $cpt, I have a "normal" curve... but I want to see dates corresponding with numbers..

Freindly,
Tanaes.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data):

You have to give `flot` timestamps, not already formated dates. For PHP use something like

```
$abscisse = strtotime($roww['SPP_DATE']) * 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you ! It work a little ! new problem appear.. It do a horizontal curve and there is several times the same date

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your problem?

Comment: Not quite, you need to seperate html (only the body goes in the html area), javascript and css. Then you have to add the javscript libraries (jquery, flot) in the menu on the left. And you have to replace all server-side code (php) with the computed data. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xY55/4/) as an example.